# How to do SUM Total in Gidview RowDataBound using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my gridview:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv_TotalAllReg" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gv_TotalAllReg_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="dt" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sno" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#f1f1f1">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="dt" DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" HeaderText="Date" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New Registrations">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Registrations" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cumulative Registrations">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_CumulativeRegistrations" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

I am showing Date wise new Registrations but I need Cumulative Registrations base on new registrations:

```
 Sno    Date           New Registrations      Cumulative Registrations
  1     12-23-2016          2
  2     12-24-2016          6
  3     12-25-2016          1
```

I need output like below and Cumulative Registration means I have created one function for display dates from 23 to 25 december 2016. So base on date getting new registration and also i want to display cumulative registrations base on new registration, base on new registration adding cum registration and how to achieve cum registration in RowDataBound .

```
 Sno    Date           New Registrations      Cumulative Registrations
  1     12-23-2016          2                         2
  2     12-24-2016          6                         8
  3     12-25-2016          1                         9
```

Below is my RowDataBound code.

```
protected void gv_TotalAllReg_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

     // e.Row.Cells.add(count.tostring());



        string Registration = string.Empty, Innovation = string.Empty;
        string daildate = gv_TotalAllReg.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString(); 



        bo.Para1 = daildate;

        DataTable dt = bl.Get_DailyReport(bo);
        ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_Registrations")).Text = dt.Rows[0]["newregistrations"].ToString();

  // my cum reg label     ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_CumulativeRegistrations")).Text

        }

       }
```

I wrote separate function for date column in gridview and on page load calling that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this. It uses the `OnRowDataBound` event to add the current Row registration count to the total and writes the current total to the Label in the Row.

```
int total = 0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the current row to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //add the registrations to the total
        total += Convert.ToInt32(row["Registrations"]);

        //find the label in the row with findcontrol and cast it back to one
        Label label = e.Row.FindControl("lbl_CumulativeRegistrations") as Label;

        //fill the label with the current total
        label.Text = string.Format("{0:N0}", total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Already I done almost functionality using RowDataBound, please can update your answer according that my above code because I am confusing stage. @VDWWD

Comment: total += Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["newregistrations"]); added like that and thank you very much and this is second time you save my life. @VDWWD